# Microsoft RDP 10 File Transfer - Specifically .mtw files in Minitab 17

Tags: remote-desktop, file-transfer, apple-remote-desktop

Does anyone know how to open files from Mac in Microsoft Remote Desktop 10? I'm specifically looking to open .mtw in Minitab 17.

I tried changing the folder to my "Macintosh HD" folder and also tried using the specific folder from "My Documents" but it still doesn't show up when I'm using Windows through RDP.

Comment: What are you connecting to?  Do you control it?  What exactly are you attempting to do?  There's a lot of details missing here.

Comment: I'm connecting it to my university's Virtual Computing Lab, using my school's user account as the admin account. 

What I'm trying to do is access .mtw files in Minitab using RDP 10. I can't manage to find where my .mtw files once I'm using Windows in RDP 10.

Under local resources, I have my folders with my Minitab .mtw files added but I think I might be using the wrong Path because it won't show up when I'm connected to Windows once I open RDP